# Attempting to install Buster with Pip on Mac

Tags: python, pip, buster.js

I am attempting to install buster with pip (sudo pip install buster) and I get this error message:

```
    The directory '/Users/user/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/user/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting buster


    u2yP9e/lxml/src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:14:10: fatal error: 'libxml/xmlversion.h' file not found
    #include "libxml/xmlversion.h"
             ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

As well as this error:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-u2yP9e/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-QVKFMY-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-u2yP9e/lxml
```

I have already installed wget.
Can anyone help?

Comment: It seems like you forgot to install `lxml`

Answer (score 1):

Solved it - had to install the command line tool for xcode